# 12.04 very slow in launching applications

Tags: 12.04

I upgraded to 12.04 and now applications are very slow to launch.  For example, I open up the update manager and after about 10 seconds the window appears with a solid white background and then I wait for about 50 seconds and nothing happens.  Then I open a Terminal and it appears very fast and the widgets in the update manager also appear.

Another example I open a terminal and I wait about 20 seconds and the Terminal window won't appear.  So then I open another Terminal and the two windows appear but it takes about 10 seconds for the prompt to appear.

I was previously running 10.10 on /dev/sda2 with my /home in /dev/sda1.  Then I installed 12.04 in /dev/sda3 and after some testing mounted /dev/sda1 to /home.

I've checked my swap (with 'free') and it exists.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps both distros having the same home folder is the problem as both will use a common .bashrc file for the settings.

Comment: this is a useful post. it may help you.
[http://askubuntu.com/questions/130499/finally-the-solution-for-slow-wireless-wifi-on-both-ubuntu-11-10-12-04][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130499/finally-the-solution-for-slow-wireless-wifi-on-both-ubuntu-11-10-12-04

Comment: @harisibrahimkv I was thinking it was my .bashrc too so I switched shells to zsh.  I think that may of fixed the problem....need more testing.  Thanks harisibrahimkv.

Comment: Most likely a missing graphic driver.

Comment: Question is 5+ years old. OP hasn't signed on in 2+ years. Question is with EOL version. Question has no answers. OP never got back via comments if switch to `zsh` was root cause or not. VTC as `not reproducible`