# I can't install Ubuntu. The error is : speech-dispatcher disabled

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit in a new Dell xps 13.

When I am trying to install appears this message:

```
 speech-dispatcher disabled
```

and after that I get a black screen.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably unrelated to speech-dispatcher; it's most likely that that's simply the last message you saw before the GUI loaded and failed to display. However, if what you've described is occurring *after you've started the installation process* and not during boot, please edit your question to indicate this. And if this answer doesn't fix your problem, please edit your question to describe exactly what steps you are following to install and everything that happens in response.

First, you should [MD5 test the `.iso` image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) you downloaded. If that doesn't check out, you'll have to redownload it and start over. Assuming that does check out, go ahead and [test your installation media for defects](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html). If that reveals a problem, then you'll have to burn the CD or write the USB flash drive over again.

If both of those tests show no errors, try [setting the `nomodeset` boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132).

Comment: Hi,I found that the problem was actually the wireless connection: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130499/how-do-i-fix-slow-wireless-on-intel-wireless-cards

Comment: @LauraLica If I understand that question correctly, the computer was still booting OK. So while your question may have the same answer, it doesn't seem like the same question. I recommend posting an answer to your own question (which you can then accept). Your answer should link to http://askubuntu.com/questions/130499/how-do-i-fix-slow-wireless-on-intel-wireless-cards but shouldn't *consist* just of that link; instead you can explain how this applies specifically to your situation. (If you really don't want to answer your own question but the problem is solved, you could delete it.)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I was using 13.x version.
It shows the message terminating all .. etc

I just hit the enter in the machine, that triggered to reboot the VM and the VM started normally.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/736807)

Comment: @AaronHill Isn't this an answer? *"just hit enter in the machine"* This might benefit from expansion and more explanation, but it seems like an attempt to answer the question. It is definitely not an attempt to ask a different question.