# Can't modify Intel wireless settings due to "FATAL: Module iwlagn not found." error

Tags: intel-wireless

I upgraded my machine to 13.04 this morning, and now it won't connect to my Wifi.  Here's the history:

I installed Ubuntu on my Windows machine using Wubi back in Version 11.10.  The Wifi didn't work then, either, but there was a little hack to fix it:

```
modprobe -r iwlagn
modprobe iwlagn bt_coex_active=0
```

And since then I just ran that at every startup, and the wifi would connect without any issue.  Now when I run it, I get this message:

```
FATAL: Module iwlagn not found.
FATAL: Module iwlagn not found.
```

Anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The intel wireless driver module appears to have been renamed. Try replacing `iwlagn` with `iwlwifi` like so:

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
```

- [How to fix slow wireless on machines with Intel wireless cards?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119578/how-to-fix-slow-wi-fi-on-thinkpads-or-other-machines-with-intel-wireless-cards)

Comment: Hey Jorge. Thanks for the tip. I tried, but it's a no-go.