# I can connect to wireless but cannot connect to internet

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, internet

I have a netbook where I use both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. One month ago I changed the router, and since that time, using Ubuntu, I can connect to Wifi but not to internet.
Anyway, using Windows I can connect to Wifi and to internet.
Moreover, using an ethernet cable, I can connect to internet also with Ubuntu.
Someone has ideas?

`iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SitecomF6E142"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:0C:F6:F6:E1:42   
      Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:3  Invalid misc:167   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW c8:0a:a9:0d:bd:70  
      indirizzo inet:192.168.0.104  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
      indirizzo inet6: fe80::ca0a:a9ff:fe0d:bd70/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6925 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6214 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      Byte RX:5865027 (5.8 MB)  Byte TX:975928 (975.9 KB)
      Interrupt:46 

lo        Link encap:Loopback locale  
      indirizzo inet:127.0.0.1  Maschera:255.0.0.0
      indirizzo inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:0 
      Byte RX:70313 (70.3 KB)  Byte TX:70313 (70.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW 00:1e:64:36:48:0a  
      indirizzo inet:192.168.0.112  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
      indirizzo inet6: fe80::21e:64ff:fe36:480a/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:625 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:565 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      Byte RX:91559 (91.5 KB)  Byte TX:71963 (71.9 KB)
```

`nm-tool`

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [SitecomF6E142] -----------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:1E:64:36:48:0A

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           150 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *SitecomF6E142:  Infra, 00:0C:F6:F6:E1:42, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 78 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.112
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1


- Device: eth0  [Connessione via cavo 1] ---------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            atl1c
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        C8:0A:A9:0D:BD:70

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.104
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1
```

`lshw -C network`

```
 *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: c0
   serial: c8:0a:a9:0d:bd:70
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:46 memory:d3500000-d353ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 00:1e:64:36:48:0a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-49-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 ip=192.168.0.112 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:44 memory:d2500000-d2501fff
```

Need something else?
Thank you.

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/119578/how-to-fix-slow-wireless-on-machines-with-intel-wireless-cards

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using same range IP address for your network interfaces.

You can simply avoid this by giving one the `192.168.0.5` and the other `192.168.10.5` with the same `255.255.255.0` mask; 
Given that your AP can handle your new IP range, everything should be OK now.

Comment: The problem wasn't the same range IP (it was setted in automatic by the OS).. Anyway I solve the problem following the instructions given at the link that chili555 suggests.