# Suddenly lost internet on all browsers

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

Suddenly lost internet access via wireless and wired. I can ping the router and the dns server.  All other computers connected to the router fine and internet is accessible. I can connect to the router from the computer in question. I have tried from 3 different browsers and I cannot get to the internet. Gateway is correct. Please help!!

Comment: If your wireless card is intel try this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/119578/how-to-fix-slow-wireless-on-machines-with-intel-wireless-cards/231064#231064

Answer (score 0):

So internet is not acessible from 1 computer but is working from othe computers? On this computer, you have ubuntu and you cannot connect to the internet using any browser?

"suddenly lost.." implies it was working and now it isnt

Can you ping yahoo.com? 
Can you ping DNS server?

Comment: Thats correct it was working fine last week. I can ping the DNS server but not yahoo. One on 1 laptop. 2 other laptops and Ipad all work fine. Ive tried uninstalling and reinstalling chrome opera and firefox. I cannot retrieve emails either. Router indicates the internet is good.

Comment: I tried changing from wireless to wired and stopping and restarting networking. Router is providing the DCHP ip.