# WIFI connection not working

Tags: wireless

I ran these commands:

```
sudo rmmod iwlwif
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
sudo su
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Now, my WiFi connection is lost and there is no WiFi option in the network manager.
How can I restore it?

Comment: Try restarting network-manager: `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: What wireless chip do you have?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *why* did you run these commands? Anyway, the last one sets up the `11n_disable=1` option for the `iwlwifi` driver. Presumably this is what is breaking your system so, just open the file `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Find this line:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

And delete it. Then reboot (not needed but it is the simplest approach). Your WiFi settings should now be back to the way they were before you broke them. I am assuming that you did all this to try and solve another issue and suggest that you might want to post a new question explaining that issue and asking for help about that.

Comment: after adding the above command my wifi connection is enabled but unable to connect to internet

Comment: @user267144 then please post a separate question about that. These sites don't work like forums, you ask a single question and get a single answer. If the answer you received solved the problem you asked about, you can mark is as accepted so the question can be marked as answered. Then, if you require further help, post a new question. Make sure you give any error messages you receive and show the output of `sudo iwconfig`.

Comment: For reference, [something like this is probably why](http://askubuntu.com/questions/119578/how-to-fix-slow-wireless-on-machines-with-intel-wireless-cards).