# WIFI connection restoring

Tags: wireless

I ran the command

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

it gives the following output in termianal

```
** (gedit: 3409): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-kFLmVcCiYa: Connection refused

(gedit: 3409): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/nitesh/. Config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

My Wi-Fi connection appears in network manager but it does not connect to the internet. This is the output of `sudo iwconfig`:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802. 11bgn  ESSID: "RFNet"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 9C:D6:43:16:21:20   
          Bit Rate=2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1457   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

How can I restore my connection?

Comment: The `sudo gedit` just opens the file `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` for editing, the warnings should not be relevant. Although it does look like you're logging in as root, is that so? If yes, don't. Anyway, the `gedit` is irrelevant, I assume you just deleted the offending line as described in your [previous question](http://askubuntu.com/q/445564/85695) right? Please _say_ so in your question.

Comment: Never use plain `sudo` to run GUI applications - use `gksudo`, `gksu` or `kdesudo` etc. depending on the variant of Ubuntu you're running. Plain `sudo` does not set the appropriate environment (in particular the `DISPLAY` variable) for root to properly communicate with the user's desktop session bus.

Comment: @steeldriver yes it does. Try `sudo env | grep -E 'DISPL|XAUT'` and you'll see that both `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` are passed to the `sudo` subshell.

Comment: @terdon interesting... that appears to be true for 13.10 but not in 12.04

Comment: if you want to view the content of a file use `sudo cat filename`. or in a gui editor use `gksu gedit filename`

Answer (score 0):

Try watching the configuration with:

```
watch ifconfig
```

in one terminal and in another:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog |grep -i Network
```

and observe those outputs while you try to connect to your wifi network