# Unstable and slow wifi in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo y510p (I am dual booting windows 8.1 and Ubuntu). I am having trouble getting good wifi speeds when I use Ubuntu. Besides, the connection is unstable and would be dropped once in a while, prompting me to re-enter the wifi password. I don't have these issues when I am on Windows 8.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 73
       serial: fc:f8:ae:d2:12:b1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-45-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 ip=x.x.x.x latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:48 memory:d5000000-d5001fff
```

*

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10286729/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: Please check this reference:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classic issue with Intel wifi since Ubuntu 12.04 and it seems that the common solution is `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and reboot

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. I found this link and tried their fixes as well.
(http://askubuntu.com/questions/119578/how-to-fix-slow-wireless-on-machines-with-intel-wireless-cards)
Now, my wifi is not as bad all the time. However, I still keep having these issues from time to time. Generally, a reboot fixes the issue.