# wifi on ubuntu works slower than wifi on windows for my laptop

Tags: wireless, internet

So the problem is this:

My laptop has a dualboot setup. It has windows-10 and Ubuntu-16.04 LTS on it. When I boot into windows and connect to the WIFI at my home, and then go to "FAST.com", I get the speed of about 30Mbps.

Now, when I boot into Ubuntu, connect to the same access point and then again test the speed at the same website, I always get approximately half of what I was getting on windows, i.e., ~15Mbps.

Can you suggest the probable cause of this issue?

EDIT:
here is the output of of the requested command:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8470]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: add the output to the question

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/119578/how-to-fix-slow-wireless-on-machines-with-intel-wireless-cards ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From a bug report a couple years ago https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1319630

I would recommend

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlopt.conf
```

Then reboot, this option enables aggressive TX