# How to fix slow wireless on machines with Intel wireless cards on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, thinkpad

I have tried ALL suggestions offered on [another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119578/how-to-fix-slow-wireless-on-machines-with-intel-wireless-cards) with no luck. my x230 with 6205 adapter does not go above 20M on 70+Mb channel on wi-fi (on Ethernet it does full 70+ Mb). None of the suggestions helped. It just same under 20Mb. :-( I have no idea what to do next. Please help
(BTW I have exactly the same problem with my Razer Blade on Linux while in Windows10 it runs fine)

Answer (score 1):

I own and use successfully two Intel wireless devices. I have honed a few techniques in several years and thousands of forum posts.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Although it did not help. My router in BT 5 router, it happily does 2.4 and 5 GHz. Both laptops connect to 5Gh. Both under Windows10 fly. But on Linux both don't go above 2Mb... :-( Still looking for help!

Comment: Your answer partially helped me. I changed the channel to 6 and the connection became more stable.