# Win 7/Ubuntu 18.04 Dual Boot slow wifi ThinkPad T420

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, thinkpad, intel-wireless

I dual booted Ubuntu onto my T420, but seems like I have some Wi-Fi issues. It's normal half the time, half the time it's slow, and sometimes, it just won't work for a minute or so. I'm not sure whether it's the drivers or something, and I'm new to Linux, so I have no idea on how to troubleshoot.
3rd party drivers are enabled already.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following info helpful:

Troubleshooting
Slow WiFi problems when using Bluetooth
Some devices like the 6235 do include a Bluetooth device in the same card, which may lead into radio conflict. Newer devices (7200 and up) try to solve them intelligently, but it is not the case of older ones.

If your WiFi is slow when using Bluetooth, try adding the following to /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf and reboot:

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8
```

from:  https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi

and

[How to fix slow wireless on machines with Intel wireless cards?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119578/how-to-fix-slow-wireless-on-machines-with-intel-wireless-cards)

Good Luck!